# Set datetime format with batch file to d/M/yyyy & HH:mm:ss

Tags: datetime, batch-file, date-formatting

How can I set the short time format of Windows to: `HH:mm:ss` 
and short date like this: `d/M/yyyy` with batch file?

And I'm in France and all the computers are in French, is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save this with `.bat` extension and run it with admin permissions:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT



[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"sDate"="/"
"sShortDate"="d/M/yyyy"
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
"sShortTime"="HH:mm"
"sYearMonth"="M yyyy"
```

This uses `REGEDIT /S` so its compatible with everything from windows XP and above.
If your machine is at least with Vista you can use `REG` [command](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) to avoid annoying output from `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` and the `cls`  . In command prompt the changes will take effect in the next cmd session.

Comment: RESPECT!  WOW you saved me, tnx alot, i can't vote up sorry but it is the real answer for me. Just another question, is it possible to install a font by batch files? if yes, where we have to put the real font? TNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: @AlirézaRtbd - just copy font files in `C:\Windows\Fonts`

Comment: Oh yes! i'll add copy to my application, merciiiii